# Can't use dep/glide packages from docker file task in azure devops to build images from other repos. Host Key Verifiaction failed error

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to use docker container task in azure DevOps pipeline to build and push images to ACR and ECR. I am able to do that through a YAML file and automate all the processes but when I am trying the same with a docker file which has dep and glide packages to fetch from other repos both from public GitHub repos and private bitbucket repos. It fails with the Host Key Verification error. The same dockerfile works with Jenkins but I don't know how to solve this ssh-key error on a Hosted Ubuntu Agent.

```
Step 13/33 : RUN curl https://glide.sh/get | sh
 ---> Running in 26f7f0a19f91
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current‌
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0‌
  0  4833    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0‌
100  4833  100  4833    0     0   6943      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  6934
ARCH=amd64‌
OS=linux
Using curl as download tool
Getting https://glide.sh/version
TAG=v0.13.3
GLIDE_DIST=glide-v0.13.3-linux-amd64.tar.gz
Downloading https://github.com/Masterminds/glide/releases/download/v0.13.3/glide-v0.13.3-linux-amd64.tar.gz
glide version v0.13.3 installed successfully
Removing intermediate container 26f7f0a19f91
 ---> d4aa1a720fab
Step 14/33 : RUN glide update --strip-vendor
 ---> Running in 4614138d27bc
[INFO]  ‌wnloading dependencies. Please wait...‌
[INFO]  ‌&gt; Fetching bitbucket.org&#x2F;myrepositoryname&#x2F;common‌
[INFO]  ‌&gt; Fetching github.com&#x2F;golang&#x2F;protobuf‌
[INFO]  ‌&gt; Fetching bitbucket.org&#x2F;myrepositoryname&#x2F;myteksi‌
[INFO]  ‌&gt; Fetching bitbucket.org&#x2F;myrepositoryname&#x2F;sdk‌
[INFO]  ‌&gt; Fetching github.com&#x2F;imdario&#x2F;mergo‌
[INFO]  ‌&gt; Fetching gopkg.in&#x2F;go-playground&#x2F;validator.v9‌
[INFO]  ‌&gt; Fetching github.com&#x2F;segmentio&#x2F;kafka-go‌
[WARN]  ‌able to checkout bitbucket.org&#x2F;myrepositoryname&#x2F;common‌
[ERROR] ‌date failed for bitbucket.org&#x2F;myrepositoryname&#x2F;common: Unable to get repository: Cloning into &#x27;&#x2F;root&#x2F;.glide&#x2F;cache&#x2F;src&#x2F;git-bitbucket.org-myrepositoryname-common.git&#x27;...‌
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
: exit status 128
Unable to get repository: Cloning into '/root/.glide/cache/src/git-bitbucket.org-myrepositoryname.git'...
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
: exit status 128
Unable to get repository: Cloning into '/root/.glide/cache/src/git-bitbucket.org-myrepositoryname.git'...
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
: exit status 128
The command &#x27;&#x2F;bin&#x2F;sh -c glide update --strip-vendor&#x27; returned a non-zero code: 1‌
##[debug]Exit code 1 received from tool '/usr/bin/docker'
##[debug]STDIO streams have closed for tool '/usr/bin/docker'
##[error]The command '/bin/sh -c glide update --strip-vendor' returned a non-zero code: 1
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]The command '/bin/sh -c glide update --strip-vendor' returned a non-zero code: 1
##[debug]Trying to logout from registry: ***
##[debug]DOCKER_CONFIG=/home/vsts/work/_temp/DockerConfig_1564846219701
##[debug]agent.tempDirectory=/home/vsts/work/_temp
##[debug]Found the Docker Config stored in the temp path. Docker config path: /home/vsts/work/_temp/DockerConfig_1564846219701/config.json, Docker config: {"auths": { "***": {"auth": "***", "email": "ServicePrincipal@AzureRM" } }, "HttpHeaders":{"X-Meta-Source-Client":"VSTS"} }
##[debug]Deleting Docker config directory. Path: /home/vsts/work/_temp/DockerConfig_1564846219701/config.json
##[debug]DOCKER_CONFIG=/home/vsts/work/_temp/DockerConfig_1564846219701
##[debug]agent.tempDirectory=/home/vsts/work/_temp
##[debug]Deleting Docker config directory. Path: /home/vsts/work/_temp/DockerConfig_1564846219701
##[debug]set DOCKER_CONFIG=
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.setvariable variable=DOCKER_CONFIG;issecret=false;]
##[debug]task result: Failed
##[error]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1
```

```
package: bitbucket.org/grabpay/ignite
import:
- package: bitbucket.org/myrepositoryname/common
  repo: git@bitbucket.org:myrepositoryname/common.git
  version: devel
  subpackages:
  - crimson
  - track
- package: bitbucket.org/myrepositoryname/myfolder1
  repo: git@bitbucket.org:myrepositoryname/myfolder1.git
  version: fface9afbb72a739d0de8c8969e0fa06fda44614
- package: bitbucket.org/myrepositoryname/myfolder2
  repo: git@bitbucket.org:myrepositoryname/myfolder2.git
  version: master
- package: github.com/imdario/mergo
  version: 2b9c8687f09d230f37f169eea24e1951bb7d1191
- package: gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9
- package: github.com/segmentio/kafka-go
- package: github.com/golang/protobuf
  version: ^1.3.1
```

The above file is the dependency repos that are to be fetched using glide.yml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it finally, what I needed was a service account which has read access to all the repos that glide is trying to access. Read access was required for all those repos with a **Bitbucket Service Connection** in Azure Pipeline. The error is not specific to glide, it is more inclined with the git repo access.